# I connected my java to mysql and my question is how do I search by fieldname with this Query? Thanks for answers in advance

Tags: java, mysql

I need help about how do search using the Field name. The ValToSearch is the characters that I entered in Text Field here is the code please check.

```
   public ArrayList<User> ListUsers(String ValToSearch)
{
    ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    
    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        String searchQuery = 
        "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE CONCAT(`ProdID`, `ProdName`, `ProdDesc`, `ProdQty`, `Price`, `Category`) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%' ORDER BY ProdID";
        rs = st.executeQuery(searchQuery);
        
        User user;
        
        while(rs.next())
        {
            user = new User(
                             rs.getInt("ProdID"),
                             rs.getString("ProdName"),
                             rs.getString("ProdDesc"),
                             rs.getInt("ProdQty"),
                             rs.getInt("Price"),
                             rs.getInt("Category")
                            );
            usersList.add(user);
        }
        
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    return usersList;
}

public void findUsers()
{
    ArrayList<User> users = ListUsers(jText_Search.getText());
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ProdID","ProdName","ProdDesc","ProdQty","Price","Category"});
    Object[] row = new Object[6];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
        row[0] = users.get(i).getId();
        row[1] = users.get(i).getFname();
        row[2] = users.get(i).getLname();
        row[3] = users.get(i).getAge();
        row[4] = users.get(i).getPr();
        row[5] = users.get(i).getCate();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
   jTable_Users.setModel(model);
   
}
```

I need help about how do search using the Field name. The ValToSearch is the characters that I entered in Text Field here is the code please check. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You need to provide more details, how are you connecting to database ? And passing parameters ?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what result you are seeing and what result you expected to see.  Given the query you have, what's wrong with it?  It isn't clear why you feel it doesn't work.

Comment: The results are okay. I can search using the the data's that I added in the table. My only concern for Example in ProdName I have Coke, Pepsi, Sprite I can search in table using those 3, so instead of using that I want to use the ProdName then name of the product Example (ProdName: Coke) then click search. After pressing the search button only the coke will appear in the table. I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: I already edited the code please check. thanks.